# How can i catch a call of public static function in PHP?

Tags: php, static, magic-methods

```
<?php
class A
{
    public static function foo()
    {
        // some action
    }

    public static function __callStatic($method, $args)
    {
        self::foo();
        static::$method($args);
    }
}

class B extends A
{
    public static function bar(){}
}
```

I search for PHP public static function handler, I try `__callStatic()` but its calling only with private and protected methods.

Answer (score 3):

Magic methods, such as [`__call` and `__callStatic`<sup>*Docs*</sup>](http://php.net/manual/language.oop5.overloading.php) are only called for methods that do not exist in your class. They are not triggered, when a normal method call happens. So the're is no way to achieve that with public methods.

However, you can make these methods private/protected, and call them in magic methods with `call_user_func` or `call_user_func_array`. Of course, returned values of these functions should also be returned by magic methods.

Comment: @madfriend: why not provide your added content as an additional answer?

Comment: I think that you've already answered what was asked. I just added my 5 pence.